# What are OpenID scopes and claims?

Tags: openid

I need to implement SSO on our web API and I was reading about OpenID and IdentityServer. This is my first connection with SSO, OAuth and OpenID.

In the presentation movies I heard a lot about scopes and claims, but the presenter never explained what each one of these actually means. I went to the official site and [searched there](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Claims), but I didn't find a definition of the terms.

So, what exactly is a scope and what is a claim?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Claims are specific attributes about a user. Wiki defines it as "A claim is a statement that one subject, such as a person or organization, makes about itself or another subject. For example, the statement can be about a name, group, buying preference, ethnicity, privilege, association or capability. ".

[Source: Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claims-based_identity)

A scope is an indication by the client that it wants to access some resource, your server may allow or reject this. [Oracle - Oauth Scopes](https://blogs.oracle.com/OracleIDM/entry/securing_access_with_oauth2_how)

To provide an example, in your application your user may have a name, email and company name - these are your claims. That client may request access to your Admin controller of your Web API, this would be a scope. In an SSO environment, it could be some other application in its own right such as another API.

Google use scopes to control access to data transfer / analytics / ads APIs
[Google Oauth Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)

Answer (score 4):

To be more specific than the previous answer:

scope: 
A scope is a space separated list of identifiers that specify what access privileges are being requested by the client application

claims: 
A claim is a key-value pair that contain some information, e.g. user information

For more details see - https://mannharleen.github.io/2020-03-11-id-access-tokens/#the-story-of-scopes--claims